# Optional Double in Realm

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I've changed a Double property from non-nullable to a nullable property.

```
var gasPressure: Double? = null
```

When starting the app I get the expected RealmMigrationNeededException with the following error:

> Property 'Measurement.gasPressure' has been made optional.

The problem is I can't find anything about making properties optional in Realm. I've found multiple people trying to do this in Swift but nothing about this in Java or Kotlin.

In the docs I've found the following, but this only tells me how to indicate a property is required.

> The @Required annotation can be used to tell Realm to disallow null values in a field, making it required rather than optional. Only Boolean, Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, byte[] and Date can be annotated with @Required. If you add it to other field types, compilation will fail.
>
> Fields with primitive types and the RealmList type are required implicitly. Fields with RealmObject type are always nullable.

Is it possible at all to have a nullable Double as property in Realm or should I use a workaround?

Comment: optional is the default - have you added the field to the schema using a migration?

Comment: The field already existed as non-optional. Should I just remove and re-add these fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is I can't find anything about making properties optional in Realm.

Well that's a shame, because you can actually do that in a migration.

```
public class MyMigration implements Realm.Migration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        if(oldVersion == someNumber) {
            RealmObjectSchema gasPipe = schema.get("GasPipe");
            if(gasPipe.isRequired("gasPressure")) {
               gasPipe.setRequired(false); // same as setNullable(true)
            }
            oldVersion++;
        }
    }

    // equals, hashcode
}
```

And you need to bump schemaVersion on the configuration

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                                  .migration(new MyMigration())
                                  .schemaVersion(someNumber+1)
                                  .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

Its happening because you have changed the Database schema.

you can check here for database migration rules.
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmMigration.html
https://medium.com/@budioktaviyans/android-realm-migration-schema-4fcef6c61e82

A github sample for migration.
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample

Comment: I know how to write Realm migrations, but I have no clue how to indicate a field has become optional. This is not explained in the links you provided.